# Spring Boot Application Running On WebLogic with Parameters

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, weblogic

I have spring boot application and I want to run it in weblogic.But I have someproperties when I execute spring with jar no problem.Also I can put these properties in application.properties and turn our package to war file.But when we deploy in weblogic ,it doesnt see this parameters in application properties.

```
 String myvalue = System.getProperty("server.servlet.contextPath"); //doesnt work in code in weblogic
```

How can we pass our system properties to web logic

Answer (score 1):

Your property is a system property, so it must be set in the java command line :

```
java -Dserver.servlet.contextPath="..."
```

or directly in your application code :

```
System.setProperty("server.servlet.contextPath","...");
```

Comment: also I dont want to add code for that reason I added application.prop but doesnt work,I can pass it for command line but I specially asked for correct way to pass these parameter in weblogic jboss

Comment: For WebLogic, the correct way is to set the system property as a jvm property  (-Dserver.servlet.contextPath="...")
If you want to read this property from the application.prop file you will have to change your code.